# Join 3 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: icon, product and menu.

```
Product-

id | menu_id
----------
1  | 1  
2  | 1
3  | 2
4  | 2
5  | 3


Menu-

id | image_id
----------
1  | 10
2  | 11
3  | 12



Icon-

id | file_url
----------
10 | www.example/....
11 | www.example/....
12 | www.example/....
```

So when I try to list each menu with assigned icon, I use :

```
    $sql = "SELECT m.id, m.category_id, m.menu_name, m.image_id, i.file_url 
            FROM menu m 
            INNER JOIN icon i
            ON i.id = m.image_id
            WHERE m.restaurant_id = '" . (int) $_SESSION['uid'] . "' 
            AND m.status='1'";
```

But I don't know how can I access to file_url in my products. So I wanna list each product with icon of menu where is assigned product.

How can I do that ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide the full schema of your tables to help us understand how your Products Table is related to the rest of the schema.

Comment: What do you mean "list each product with icon of menu where is assigned product"? Are you using `PHP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another join, i.e. something like that:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id, m.menu_name, m.image_id, i.file_url 
            FROM product p 
            INNER JOIN menu m ON m.id = p.menu_id
            INNER JOIN icon i ON i.id = m.image_id
            WHERE ... ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join more than 2 tables, the syntax is the exact same, so what you'd want is:

```
    SELECT
         <stuff, including i.file_url>
    FROM
        menu m 
        JOIN product p on m.id = p.menu_id
        JOIN icon i on i.id = m.image_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the following, add the variables you want, but the join will be something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM Product AS PROD
INNER JOIN Menu AS MNU
ON PROD.Menu_ID = MNU.ID
INNER JOIN ICON AS ICN
ON MNU.Image_ID = ICN.ID
```